# Why does Rust output escape backslashes on paths in windows? What is best way to remove the extra backslashes from output?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

**Background**

Writing a program that watches a directory and subdirs and alerts user when file(s) in the path are created, updated, edited.  Code is shared on [github](https://github.com/raddevus/watcher).

I'm new to Rust (about 1 week of experience).

**Make Output Path Easy to Use**

I want user to be able to easily copy the output path (see pic below) and copy / paste it for use.

When I run the program on Linux it works great with directory separators (/ - forward slash) and the user can easily copy the path and use it.

**Problem : Windows Platform Uses Backslashes**

The problem is that on Windows platform paths are separated by backslashes (which are also escape chars).

**Double-Backslashes**

When the program outputs the path on Windows it always shows double backslashes and the path isn't easily copy-able.

Here's a snapshot of the output:

[image: double backslashes on win10]

As an example I am using the following output:

```
println!("{:?}", Path::new("c:\\windows\\"));
```

The output is from the Path::new() method itself, but it always outputs the path string with the double backslashes.

Can you help me find a better way to format the output so that it has single backslashes like a normal path (which excludes the escape backslashes)?

**EDIT**

Someone mentioned trying raw string input so I tried the following:

```
println!("{:?}", Path::new(r"c:\windows\"));
```

However, the Path::new method still outputs double backslashes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I know how to create verbatim strings in .NET with @ but wasn't sure how to do that in Rust. 
However, I changed the code where the path is created and used the raw as input  ==> println!("{:?}", Path::new(r"c:\windows\"));   But the output still carries the double backslashes (via the Path object -- or whatever that is called in Rust).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Problem is that you are using the `Debug` formatting to print the path, this causes characters that would need to be escaped in a string literal to be escaped in the output.

Instead you should use the normal `Display` formatting, though as Path does not directly implement `Display` you will need to call display on the path to display it.

```
println!("{}", Path::new("c:\\windows\\").display());
```

Note that `Path::display` is not loss-less in case the path contains non-unicode data.